# Is there a shortcut key for changing Google Sheets text color to the "last color"?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, text-formatting

I often find myself changing text colors to the same color for five minutes at a time which is really unnecessarily mouse-intensive.

Comment: I'd rather use autoformat and change a value of some cell (autoformat can apply to a cell based on other cell value, use "formula" method)

Comment: @LogicDaemon if you think this is a valuable way to do this, please write up a fully functional answer.

Comment: It will not be doing exactly "this". To apply autoformatting, the whole workflow will have to change. But without any specifics, I cannot advise any further, this is why it's a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 11):

If the last action that you made was to apply the color then use Redo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd>

Answer (score 11):

Here are the steps:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
2. Type the color (eg. blue, red etc)
3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> is like a command palette for all available commands. It's in `Help` menu.

Comment: For changing a color to "dark green 3", that's still quite a lot of keys to press.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is **no** for:

> shortcut key for changing text color to the last color?

but you can always make one for color change:

- first you will need to click on the toolbar/ribbon to escape the cell

  [image: 0]
- now use this combo:

  ---

  ## [image] 10x + [image] 15x + [image] 3x + select color
- now you can use something like **[AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/)** to save this combo (including that initial click) under one key. for example:

  - red color under **F7** key: 

    ```
    click + tab (10x) + right arrow (15x) + down arrow (4x) + right arrow (1x) + enter
    ```
  - reset (black) color under **F8** key: 

    ```
    click + tab (10x) + right arrow (15x) + down arrow (1x) + enter
    ```

Comment: Based on SM Adnan's answer, I've been using the following script in AHK:
F7::
Send, {alt down}
Send, {/ down}
Send, {alt up}
Send, {/ up}
Sleep 100
Send, red
Send, {Down}
Send, {Down}
Send, {Enter}
return

Comment: Nowadays you need 13×tab + 17×→. Might depend on your system and google account features, though.

Answer (score 4):

1. Copy the cell that has the formatting that you need (Ctrl+C)
2. Paste format only on top of the cell(s) that you want to be formatted the same way (Ctrl+Alt+V)

Answer (score -2):

No there is not. But you can try following topic? maybe it will be a solution for you, to override some keys on new ones.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/docs/docs-community/lOia0JT4dX4

Comment: The related thread is very old. The  initial post was posted almost 10 years ago and was locked on 2010.